# Why do my boxes go flat when I make them into a link

Tags: html, css

I'm creating 4 boxes that represent a page. Right now, they show up correctly.
[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIIXY.jpg)

That result was achieved by this code:

HTML

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box carpet">
                <p>Carpet Cleaning</p>

                <img class="box" src="images/carpet.jpg" alt="carpet cleaning" />
                <img class="box box-overlay box-overlay-carpet" src="images/overlay.png" />
            </div>


            <div class="box upholstery">
                <p class="long-name">Upholstery Cleaning</p>

                <img class="box" src="images/upholstery.jpg" alt="upholstery cleaning" />
                <img class="box box-overlay box-overlay-upholstery" src="images/overlay.png" />
            </div>

            <div class="box area-rug">
                <p class="long-name">Area Rug Cleaning</p>

                <img class="box" src="images/area-rug.jpg" alt="area rug cleaning" />
                <img class="box box-overlay box-overlay-area-rug" src="images/overlay.png" />
            </div>

            <div class="box vct">
                <p>VCT Cleaning</p>

                <img class="box" src="images/vct.jpg" alt="vct cleaning" />
                <img class="box box-overlay box-overlay-vct" src="images/overlay.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background: #F2F2F2;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin: 0;
}

div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 95%;
}

/***********/
/* Content */
/***********/

.content {
    background: url("images/desert.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
}

.content .boxes {
    margin-top: 83px;
    background: black;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.content .box {
    width: 25%;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: left;
}

.content .box-overlay,
.content .box p {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
}

.content .box p {
    z-index: 100;
    display: inline;
    margin: 37% 25%;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 150%;
}

.content .box .long-name {
    margin-right: 15%;
    margin-left: 15%;
}

.content .box img {
    width: 100%;
}

.content .box-overlay {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.content .box-overlay-carpet {
    background: #00DAFF;
}

.content .carpet:hover {
    background: #00B0CC;
}

.content .carpet:hover > p {
    color: #E5BF00;
}

.content .box-overlay-upholstery {
    background: #00FF21;
}

.content .upholstery:hover {
    background: #00CC17;
}

.content .upholstery:hover > p {
    color: #E5BF00;
}

.content .box-overlay-area-rug {
    background: #FFD800;
}

.content .area-rug:hover {
    background: #CCAA00;
}

.content .area-rug:hover > p {
    color: #E5BF00;
}

.content .box-overlay-vct {
    background: #FF2B00;
}

.content .vct:hover {
    background: #CC2100;
}

.content .vct:hover > p {
    color: #E5BF00;
}
```

However, I need the boxes to be clickable. So in the HTML, I simply removed the p elements and replaced them with a elements wrapping around the text and img elements. I also changed p elements in CSS to a elements.

The result? Everything disappeared.

I do realize that my knowledge of web development is in the growing phase, but I would like to know what's causing the style to break down from simply changing p elements to a elements.

Here's the final code:

HTML

```
    <div class="content">
       <div class="container">
           <div class="boxes">
               <div class="box carpet">
                <a href="#">
                    Carpet Cleaning

                    <img class="box" src="images/carpet.jpg" alt="carpet cleaning" />
                    <img class="box box-overlay box-overlay-carpet" src="images/overlay.png" />
                </a>
               </div>


               <div class="box upholstery">
                   <a href="#" class="long-name">
                       Upholstery Cleaning

                    <img class="box" src="images/upholstery.jpg" alt="upholstery cleaning" />
                    <img class="box box-overlay box-overlay-upholstery" src="images/overlay.png" />
                </a>
               </div>

               <div class="box area-rug">
                   <a href="#" class="long-name">
                       Area Rug Cleaning

                    <img class="box" src="images/area-rug.jpg" alt="area rug cleaning" />
                    <img class="box box-overlay box-overlay-area-rug" src="images/overlay.png" />
                </a>
               </div>

               <div class="box vct">
                   <a href="#">
                       VCT Cleaning

                    <img class="box" src="images/vct.jpg" alt="vct cleaning" />
                    <img class="box box-overlay box-overlay-vct" src="images/overlay.png" />
                </a>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background: #F2F2F2;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin: 0;
}

div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 95%;
}

/***********/
/* Content */
/***********/

.content {
    background: url("images/desert.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
}

.content .boxes {
    margin-top: 83px;
    background: black;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.content .box {
    width: 25%;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: left;
}

.content .box-overlay,
.content .box a {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
}

.content .box a {
    z-index: 100;
    display: inline;
    margin: 37% 25%;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 150%;
}

.content .box .long-name {
    margin-right: 15%;
    margin-left: 15%;
}

.content .box img {
    width: 100%;
}

.content .box-overlay {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.content .box-overlay-carpet {
    background: #00DAFF;
}

.content .carpet:hover {
    background: #00B0CC;
}

.content .carpet:hover > a {
    color: #E5BF00;
}

.content .box-overlay-upholstery {
    background: #00FF21;
}

.content .upholstery:hover {
    background: #00CC17;
}

.content .upholstery:hover > a {
    color: #E5BF00;
}

.content .box-overlay-area-rug {
    background: #FFD800;
}

.content .area-rug:hover {
    background: #CCAA00;
}

.content .area-rug:hover > a {
    color: #E5BF00;
}

.content .box-overlay-vct {
    background: #FF2B00;
}

.content .vct:hover {
    background: #CC2100;
}

.content .vct:hover > a {
    color: #E5BF00;
}
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html_blocks.asp

Comment: You need to only show the smallest working code. See [this](/help/mcve) link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you are using "p" tag you are wrapping only text content whereas when you are using "a"  tag you are wrapping text and the images ... so this is the root of your problem.
wrap only text in  and problem will be solved
Example:

```
<div class="box area-rug">
               <a href="#" class="long-name">
                   Area Rug Cleaning</a>

                <img class="box" src="images/area-rug.jpg" alt="area rug cleaning" />
                <img class="box box-overlay box-overlay-area-rug" src="images/overlay.png" />

           </div>
```

and if you are trying to make wholething clickable then wrap "a" tag to whole "div" 
Example:

```
<a href="#">
        <div class="box upholstery">
            <p class="long-name">Upholstery Cleaning</p>

            <img class="box" src="images/upholstery.jpg" alt="upholstery cleaning" />
            <img class="box box-overlay box-overlay-upholstery" src="images/overlay.png" />
        </div></a>
```

Comment: Excellent. Wrapping the "a" tag around the "div" works like a charm. However, the HTML now looks a bit odd to me. Instead of a new box starting with the "div" tag, it now starts with the "a" tag.

Oh well, not a huge deal. Thank you!

EDIT: I was able to take @Adrian's suggest of wrapping the contents of the div in an "a" tag and now the HTML looks a lot cleaner. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

`p` and `a` are not interchangeable from a layout perspective: `p` is a `block` tag, while `a` is an `inline` tag. This has a significant impact on the flow of content on the page; while block elements have a bounding box, inline elements flow with the content on the page - think of the behavior of `p` versus `i`. If you put content in a `p` tag, it will be on its own line, with content before and after it; if you put content in an `i` tag, it will flow normally with the text around it, including word wrapping in the middle of the tag contents.

If you use an `a` element *inside* the existing `p` element, you should get the behavior you're looking for.

Also note @BaDsHahSHIVAM's answer - you not only changed what tag you were using, but *what it's contents are*. This will also have a significant impact on the layout of the page. There are many ways to deal with this:

- Wrap the entire `div` in an `a`
- Wrap the entire contents of the `div` in an `a`
- Wrap the contents of the `p` and each `img` in separate `a` tags, each with the same `href`

Comment: Very useful information. Thank you! One thing, though: the previously used "p" tag was set to be displayed as inline - not as its default block. That's why I thought changing the "p" tag to an "a" tag would give the same results but clickable. I was able to fix my issue thanks to both you and @BaDsHahSHIVAM. But do you know why the layout went nuts when the "p" tag changed to an "a" tag, both of which are displaying as inline?

Comment: Because they had different contents: your `p` example contained only the text, while your `a` example contained the text *and the images*. Also note that making `p` inline is pretty bad practice - the entire purpose of `p` is to be a block level (paragraph) element. If you want a generic inline container, use `span`, that's what it's made for.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to make the boxes themselves clickable by using the following code:

```
<div class="box" onclick="location.href='#'">
```

This will make the whole box clickable. You could also make it apparent that the box is clickable by changing the cursor style:

```
<div class="box" onclick="location.href='#';" style="cursor:pointer;">
```